# Load Balancer with Zero Trust Tunnels

Tags: load-balancing, cloudflare

has anyone used cloudflare's load balancer having tunnel in the origin pool? I have verified that the tunnels themselves are working but when sending a request via the load balancer it gets caught by the tunnel's catch all rule.

I've tested the tunnels by curling from it's public hostname and it works. The health monitor on the load balancer also says that the origin pool is healthy. I can ping the load balancer using it's hostname, but can't curl using the load balancer. Experimenting with the catch all rule, I'm sure that the curl attempt using the load balancer's hostname attempts to access the tunnel, but fails for some reason and I get the catch all rule output.

What could be causing the load balancer to be caught by the catch all rule of the tunnel?

I have followed the documentation on making a tunnel for a private IP/port, and have tested it by curling from it directly. The health monitor on the load balancer says all the pools are healthy.